# php my admin: no database selected

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to learn php and mysql. So i tried making a database using phpmyadmin and connect it with my php.
Here is a simple example where I try to see if the database is working

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if(!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("nameofdatabase",$connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Databases</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nameofdatabasetable", $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed::: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[1];
}

?>

</body>
  </html>
<?php
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

and i get

```
 Database query failed::: No database selected
```

which means than this part of code

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users", $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed::: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[1];
}

?>
```

is not working (i put a different number of these ":" in each if.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Since you are trying to learn php and sql: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: thank, i wasn t aware of this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic for your code doesn't make sense because if the connection doesn't happen then you would not be able to select a database and your database select statement is within the logic for if you cannot connect to the database. Try this instead:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root"); 
if(!$connection) { 
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
}else{
   $db_select = mysql_select_db("nameofdatabase",$connection); 
   if (!$db_select) { 
       die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error()); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to pass the username and password in the mysql_connect call.  Here is my database open() function.

```
    $this->con_error = "";

    $db_con= mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password);

    if (!$db_con) 
    {
        $this->con_error = mysql_error();
        return false;
    }       
    if(!mysql_select_db($this->database))
    {
        $this->con_error = mysql_error();
        return false;
    }

    return $db_con;
```

Comment: `die(); return;` is a silly construct.  Omit the return.  It will never execute.

Comment: True.  As my class evolved I started saving the mysql_error and simple returning true/false.  Then I could reference the error later, if I wanted.

Comment: Frank Farmer, updated my code to address your comment.  Also stored the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
$db_select = mysql_select_db("nameofdatabase",$connection);
```

`mysql_select_db` cannot possibly run here.  It's only called after die.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if(!$connection) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
$db_select = mysql_select_db("nameofdatabase",$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
  die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also it would be worth checking if you entered a password to your server.
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root"); (Missing Password)

The following code will trap any other error that might be happening and like the answer below this will provide mysql conectivity errors in case there is any.

```
    try 
   {
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password");
        if(!$connection) {   
          die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());   
        }   
        $db_select = mysql_select_db("nameofdatabase",$connection);   
        if (!$db_select) {   
          die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error());   
         }   

   }catch (Exception $e){
       error_log(" DB Error: ".$e->getMessage());
   }
```